# Improving performance of fitting data

Tags: python, performance, array

I wrote the following code. A user in STACKOVERFLOW website recommended me to write my code here in order to be reviewed for optimization.
How could I optimize it?
Could I have this code in a pro and better form and performance?

EXPLANATION: This code calculate multiplication of three matrix in `c()` function. Then, using `Omo` as `old` and `Omn` as new into `c()` calculate `L()`.Finally, defining two `if` statement accept `L`s which are bigger than `1` and `R3` which is random number. THIS CODE IS MCMC FITING DATA. HERE I FIT `omn` and `Mn`.

```
import numpy as np
import emcee
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.integrate import odeint
O_m=chi=None
xx=np.array([0.01,0.012])  
yy=np.array([32.95388698,33.87900347])
Cov=[[137,168],[28155,-2217]]     # this is a covariance matrix for simplification I chose the 2*2 one

temp=1e5
z0=0
M=2
Omo = 0.3
Odo=0.7
H0=70

def ant(z, Om, Od):
    return 1/sqrt(((1+z)**2)*(1+Om*z)-z*(2+z)*Od)
def dl(n, Om, Od, M):
    Od=1-Om
    q=quad(ant,0,xx[n],args=(Om,Od))[0]
    h=5*log10((1+xx[n])*q)
    fn=(yy[n]-M-h)                  
    return fn

def c(Om, Od, M):
    f_list = []
    for i in range(2):  # the value '2' reflects matrix size
        f_list.append(dl(i,Om,Od,M))
    rdag=[f_list]
    rmat=[[f] for f in f_list]
    a=np.dot(rdag,Cov)
    b=np.dot(a,rmat)
    Matrix=np.linalg.det(b)*0.000001
    return Matrix
N=2000
with open('txtfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range (1,N):
        R1=np.random.uniform(0,1)
        R2=np.random.uniform(0,1)
        R3=np.random.uniform(0,1)
        R4=np.random.uniform(0,1)
        def delta(r1, r2):
            sig=0.04
            d=sig*(np.sqrt(-2*np.log(r1))*np.cos(np.radians(r2)))
            return d
        Omn=Omo+delta(R1, R2)
        Odn=1-Omn
        Mn=M+delta(R3,R4)
        R3=np.random.uniform(0,1)

        def L():
            l=np.exp(-0.5*(c(Omn,Odn,Mn)-c(Omo,Odo,M)))
            return l
        if L()>1:
            O_m=Omn
            chi=c(Omn,Odn,Mn)

        elif L()>R3:
            O_m=Omn
            chi=c(Omn, Odn, Mn)


        f.write("{0}\t{1}\n".format(chi, O_m))
    print("Minimum of chi squre is")
    if chi<temp:
        temp=chi
        chimin=temp
    print(chimin)
    print(input("Press any key to exit... "))
```

I appreciate your help and your attention